# How to save in global environment immediately using gwidgets?

Tags: r, gwidgets

I'm currently building a GUI in R which uses a Google API. I'm using gwidgets2 and when I add a handler to the button I expect it to save the output in my global environment.

```
addHandlerClicked(search_button, handler = function(h,...) {
  .GlobalEnv$output = api_call(svalue(txt_pattern1),lon,lat,50000,NULL,api_key)


})
```

However, only when I close the window and run the script again does it then only show that it has saved in the global environment. i.e. output will show in global environment. How can I fix this so that after I click the button it stores in global environment?

Comment: Do you know about the `assign` function?

Comment: It does the same thing with assign(). I only once I run the script to open the window again then does it show that the variable has been assigned.

Comment: How are you using `assign` in this case?  Add that to your question so we can see.

Comment: As  `assign("output",find_places(svalue(txt_pattern1),lon,lat,50000,NULL,api_key),.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: withinin the handler of `addHandlerClicked`

Comment: Yup, that's it. Assignment within a function call must use a trick to make the binding persist outside of the scope of the function. Using `<<-` and `assign`, or an explicit environment are some of the options.